# pass variables and execute functions

Tags: jquery, json

I'm a coding newbie and mostly learning stuff here and there. I tried to load json array data via jquery and formated it with html/css. This section has been successful. Now I'm trying to display the previous and the next data set but I only can get it display in console log. I think the issue might be around how to execute format function again after click the next/prev button, but I don't know how to fix this exactly...I think I miss some foundation knowledge...This shouldn't be that hard, please hint and help...Thank you.

```
//Loading JSON
jQuery.getJSON("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1972456/data/works.json", function(data){
    var i = 0;

    // console.log(data.works[0]);
    jQuery.each(data, function format(){
        $(".aboutWork").html('<h1>' + data.works[i].title + '</h1>');
        $('<h2>' + data.works[i].des + '</h2>').appendTo(".aboutWork");
        $('<p>' + data.works[i].detail + '</p>').appendTo(".aboutWork");
    });     

    $("#next").click(function(){

        i++;
        console.log(data.works[i]);
    });

    $("#prev").click(function(){
        i--;
        console.log(data.works[i]);
    });
});
```

Comment: You have a bunch of coding errors here, but it is not clear what you want to have happen.  You get some JSON data and you iterate over it with `.each()` (several coding errors in that, but I don't know what you're trying to accomplish).  What exactly do you want to have happen with the `.each()`?  And, what are the `.click()` handlers supposed to do?

Comment: Also I have noticed you have asked 7 questions now and have  yet to mark any answers as accepted.  Mark answers as accepted or give feedback if answers did not resolve your question.  People will be less inclined to help you in the future if you don't accept their answers.

Comment: oh ya, that's true...thanks for the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**this might be easier**

```
$.getJSON('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1972456/data/works.json', function (data) {
    var i=0,il=data.works.length-1;
    function format() { $('.aboutWork').html('<h1>'+data.works[i].title+'</h1><h2>'+data.works[i].des+'</h2><p>'+data.works[i].detail+'</p>'); }//print info
    format();//run initial
    $('#next,#prev').on('click', function(){
        if ($(this).prop('id')==='next' && i<il) { i++; format(); }//add
        else if ($(this).prop('id')==='prev' && i>0) { i--; format(); }//subtract
    });
});
```

This prints the first, and reruns the function when the buttons are clicked as long as `i` is in the range of the array.

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/rqUsR/

Comment: nice code optimization, however the only potential issue I see is that you are making a new http request for every (next/prev) click, even when you reached the limit.

Comment: got it all fixed, and it's pretty sturdy now

Answer (score 0):

Try

**EDIT #2** : optimized code

```
function populate(data,i) {
    $(".aboutWork").attr("id", "d" + data.works[i].id).html('<h1>' + data.works[i].title + '</h1>');
    $('<h2>' + data.works[i].des + '</h2>').appendTo(".aboutWork");
    $('<p>' + data.works[i].detail + '</p>').appendTo(".aboutWork");
}

jQuery.getJSON("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1972456/data/works.json", function (data) {
    var i = 0;
    jQuery.each(data, function format() {
        populate(data,i);
    });

    $(".nav").click(function (event) {
        if (event.target.id == "next") {
            if (i < (data.works.length - 1)) {
                i++;
                populate(data,i);
            } 
        } else if (event.target.id == "prev") {
            if (i > 0) {
                i--;
                populate(data,i);
            } 
        }
    });

});
```

See latest **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RQe83/)**

**NOTICE** that I added an `ID` to the `div` for demo purposes

Comment: not sure that there's a need for `each`, or for `populate` to be outside of `getJSON`, you can do it all inside without `each`, and just using `format` to do the work.

Comment: @FiLeVeR10 : yes you are right, the `each` comes from the original tweaked post